# How to extract/read specific information from a data frame, to make plots

Tags: pandas, indexing

It has been a while.   I have figured out several different ways of reading in csv/TXT/xls files and done rudimentary data plots.   Now, I have a two-fold question. My first question is (based on a conversation I had with coworkers) is this the best way to read the data into a frame, or should it be done in a different manner?   I have thousands of CSV files from a project, with 5 columns of data I am interested in.

These are now read into a df and listed in a way that I like.  As a career software user, I'm at a disadvantage now.  Normally in a spreadsheet, I would select, then plot the ones I want, but that's not why we use python.

Each CSV starts with the CSV file name, then colon, then the first column.  I would like to selectively fetch data based on file name (this is what I haven't figured out), and plot x,y based on column names (I have this figured out for a single CSV file).

Next question is how can this be done (extract selectively for plotting)?  Each file has 93 rows, and there are many in a single frame. So take "this" sample and "that" sample for x,y plot comparison), or should I read in the data another way, such as separate dataframes (this was also suggested)?

This would be extracting one set of 93 rows selectively from amongst the many present in a dataframe.

````
#Created on Thu Feb 17 10:04:22 2022

import pandas as pd
import os
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

path=r"C:path"    # sets file path
os.chdir(path)    #this tells python to change working directory to file path

path = os.getcwd()
cols=[4,10,11,12,13]   # use only these columns (may have to cheat and look in excel to find the ones you want)  


csvs = [x for x in os.listdir('.') if x.endswith('.csv')]
# stats.csv -> stats
fns = [os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(x))[0] for x in csvs]

d = {}
for i in range(len(fns)):
    d[fns[i]] = pd.read_csv(csvs[i],low_memory=True, usecols=cols, header=2)


#the next part is for creating plots and subplots, and goes beyond the curent question I believe``` 


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dACP6.jpg
````

Comment: `My first question is ... is this the best way to read the data into a frame`. If you have many CSVs and you wanna batch process them, then I would say, yes, reading the csv into a dataframe and use python is good.

Comment: `Can this be done, or should I read in the data another way?` can **WHAT** be done? What is your 'this'?

Comment: @RaymondKwok (question edited) Fourth paragraph.  Extract select rows (in groups of ~93) selectively

Comment: #1 `d[fns[0]]` is a dataframe, right? #2 you know which column name as `x` and you know which column name as `y` right? #3 Assume the column name for `x` is `col_x`, and that for `y` is `col_y` #4 then you can plot all the rows from d[fns[0]] with `d[fns[0]].plot(x='col_x', y='col_y')`

Comment: thank you, @RaymondKwok.   But what I asked is not columns, but rows.  If I were using excel, I would arrange these side by side, not verticallly concantenated.  In HTML one can target a point on a webpage, and call to that.   This is what I have in mind.

hundreds of files, filename as a header, column names as a subheader, then 93 rows of numbers.  

I want to call on certain groups, and plot overlays.  plotting specific columsn is not hard, but I want to plot rows/groups of rows.

Maybe I can illustrate this.  A picture being worth a 1000 words and such.

Comment: you can easily swap rows/columns with `df.transpose()`